# Museums in Germany about the First World War

Tags: germany, museums, military

In Germany there are many museums about the [Second World War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II) and the Nazi regime. But are there also museums about the [First World War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I) or at least history museums with exhibitions about the war?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question because I was also wondering about a museum which only shows the First World War. I have not found something like that, but there are exhibitions in some museums

Bayerisches Armeemuseum (Bavarian Army Museum), Ingolstadt
http://www.bayerisches-armeemuseum.de/de/ausstellungen/dauerausstellungen/der-erste-weltkrieg.html

Wehrgeschichtliches Museum (Museum of military history), Rastatt
http://www.wgm-rastatt.de/ausstellungen/dauerausstellung/der-erste-weltkrieg/

The seemingly best museum is not in Germany, but in Somme, France: "Historial de la Grande Guerre"

Answer (score 11):

Not in *Germany*, but within reach: When in school, our class went on a day trip from Germany to [Verdun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdun), *France*.

We visited [Fort Douaumont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Douaumont), the [Douaumont ossuary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douaumont_ossuary), and the [museum](http://www.memorialdeverdun.fr/index.php/index_uk.html). Finally - perhaps as a contrast - we went to the city of Verdun, which I remember as picturesque.

I highly recommend visiting the Verdun battlefield if you are interested in WWI [trench warfare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trench_warfare). Thinking about the visit still gives me chills.

Comment: Schools go on day trips to other countries? Wow.

Comment: The school is in [a city near the border](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=karlsruhe,+germany&hl=de&ie=UTF8&ll=49.009051,8.379822&spn=0.287803,0.441513&sll=49.001844,8.381195&sspn=0.287845,0.441513&hnear=Karlsruhe,+Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg,+Deutschland&t=m&z=11).